# Good Values for Knuth's multiplication method - Hashing

Tags: hash

Any guesses what are good values for the "c"?

```
// h(k) = ⌊(m · (k · c − ⌊k · c⌋)⌋
return (int) Math.floor(distinctElements * (key * c - Math.floor(key * c)));
```

I have found the this one: (Math.sqrt(5)-1)/2)

However are there any other good choices known?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The value you've found is the number known as phi (φ), the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). It's not actually correct to use that... what you should be using is its multiplicative inverse, φ^-1. φ^-1 and φ^-2 have the special property of tending to optimally spread out the hash values regardless of the range of your inputs.

However, for sufficiently large range, pretty much any irrational number will do.